Multi-line Truncated Text with "..." in the end
I need help with Multi-line Truncated Text. I can't cut the final word with "..." in text block with randon string number
So this is my solution which cut the end of my block, but without "..."
      <ul className="note__tags">
        {tags.map((item) => (
          <li className="note__tag-item">{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

 &__text {
    @include manrope-15($size: 15px, $weight: 500, $color: $grey-blue);
    width: 270px;
    max-height: 192px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: wrap;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

And i tried somthing like this, but it look's like strange and not flexible.
 &__text {
    @include manrope-15($size: 15px, $weight: 500, $color: $grey-blue);
    width: 270px;
    max-height: 192px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: wrap;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
      content:"...";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 40px;
      color: black;
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/. You'll need to use -webkit-line-clamp. With the -webkit- prefix it has widespread browser support.

you want to truncate the text based on the number of lines, rather than the number of characters. If you need to truncate based on characters, you can modify the JavaScript code accordingly
<div class="note__text">
  {your_text_here}
</div>

.note__text {
  @include manrope-15($size: 15px, $weight: 500, $color: $grey-blue);
  width: 270px;
  max-height: 192px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

const textElement = document.querySelector('.note__text');
const maxHeight = 192; // adjust this value to your needs
const lineHeight = 15; // adjust this value to your needs (font size)
const linesToShow = Math.floor(maxHeight / lineHeight);

const text = textElement.textContent;
const words = text.split(' ');
let truncatedText = '';

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  truncatedText += words[i] + ' ';
  if (i >= linesToShow - 1) {
    truncatedText += '...';
    break;
  }
}

textElement.textContent = truncatedText.trim();


How to Truncate Text with CSS and JavaScript
: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-truncate-text-with-css-javascript/

Different ways to truncate text with CSS : https://blog.logrocket.com/ways-truncate-text-css/



I don't really understand what a "random string number" is, but if you mean a "long string of random numbers", Try this:


.content {
  width: 12rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.line-clamp-2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
.break-all {
  word-break: break-all;
}
<div class="content line-clamp-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea tempore repellendus ut consequatur dolorem ducimus.</div>
<div class="content line-clamp-2 break-all">1234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345</div>
<div class="content line-clamp-2 break-all">The longest word is pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</div>



You can change the number of lines displayed with -webkit-line-clamp: <integer [1,∞]>.

Achieve a multi-line truncated text effect with ellipsis at the end, you can use the CSS -webkit-line-clamp property along with the -webkit-box display model.


.line-clamp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: var(--line-clamp, 1);
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<div class="line-clamp" style="--line-clamp: 3;">
  This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end. This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.This is a long paragraph that will be clamped after three lines of text, showing ellipsis at the end.
</div>




You use the number of strings, but in my case it's the random number
